# Efficient way to store millions of arrays, and perform IN check

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

There are around 3 millions of arrays - or Python lists\tuples (does not really matter). Each array consists of the following elements:

```
['string1', 'string2', 'string3', ...]  # totally, 10000 elements
```

These arrays should be stored in some kind of key-value storage. Let's assume now it's a Python's dict, for a simple explanation.

So, 3 millions of keys, each key represents a 10000-elements array.

Lists\tuples or any other custom thing - it doesn't really matter. What matters is that arrays should consist strings - utf8 or unicode strings, from 5 to about 50 chars each. There are about 3 millions of possible strings as well. It is possible to replace them with integers if it's really needed, but for more efficient further operations, I would prefer to have strings.

Though it's hard to give you a full description of the data (it's complicated and odd), it's something similar to synonyms - let's assume we have 3 millions of words - as the dict keys - and 10k synonyms for each of the word - or element of the list.

Like that (not real synonyms but it will give you the idea):

```
{
    'computer': ['pc', 'mac', 'laptop', ...],  # (10k totally)
    'house': ['building', 'hut', 'inn', ...],  # (another 10k)
     ...
}
```

Elements - 'synonyms' - can be sorted if it's needed.

Later, after the arrays are populated, there's a loop: we go thru all the keys and check if some var is in its value. For example, user inputs the words 'computer' and 'laptop' - and we must quickly reply if the word 'laptop' is a synonym of the word 'computer'. The issue here is that we have to check it millions of time, probably 20 millions or so. Just imagine we have *a lot* of users entering some random words - 'computer' and 'car', 'phone' and 'building', etc. etc. They may 'match', or they may not 'match'.

So, in short - what I need is to:

- store these data structures memory-efficiently,
- be able to quickly check if some item is in array.

I should be able to keep memory usage below 30GB. Also I should be able to perform all the iterations in less than 10 hours on a Xeon CPU.

It's ok to have around 0.1% of false answers - both positive and negative - though it would be better to reduce them or don't have them at all.

What is the best approach here? Algorithms, links to code, anything is really appreciated. Also - a friend of mine suggested using bloom filters or marisa tries here - is he right? I didn't work with none of them.

Comment: Do you need to keep them in RAM? I'd look into something like HDF5 files, that are designed for this kind of use.

Comment: (ok, HDF5 is not the thing for you, because it's meant for numerical data, but you get the point)

Comment: @RicardoCárdenes well, a single-node cluster will work just too slow using HDD. Disk operations are extremely slow. I doubt that even SDD would help a lot. Also I would not like to complicate things and create a multi-node cluster. If it's possible to avoid doing so and keep everything in RAM, then it should be the way it goes.

Comment: What do you mean by "all the iterations in under 10 hours"? Also, "by memory usage under 30GB", do you mean for the whole data structure? That will be difficult, as storing just the strings, leaving out which map to which, will take well over 100GB without compression.

Comment: Do you work for the NSA? ;-)

Comment: Or just simply use a relationship database, for these hughe datastructures they are really great. Or you would need two dictionaries, one with all the possible words and a uniqueue ID, then a alias dictionary with `word -> ID` in order to minemise duplicate word objects. This is just a slim basic word opemization where multiple useage of words come into play, again.. databases have extremely more complex and well developed optemizations for these kind of things. Not to mention compression ratios..

Comment: Do you expect the data access pattern to be uniformly random, or is it reasonable to expect some of 'keys' to be accessed more than others?

Comment: One simple idea would be to replace the list of synonyms with a set. This would make it faster to check if items are present in it.

Comment: Sounds like you could run the same algorithm with a set of pairs of synonyms instead (with the pairs' values internally sorted to avoid having to duplicate every entry), and could either use string interning to reduce memory usage, or store only hashes and accept some error.

Comment: what about using Redis or some memory caching ?

Comment: @sweeneyrod 10 hours mean than all the operations - both creating the structures and that 20millions loop - should take not more than 10 hours

Comment: @martineau don't get me wrong but if NSA hire me then it would be the end of the world for them - considering my 'high' skills, everybody should avoid hiring me haha =))

Comment: @Torxed well I guess rdbms'es have a big overhead... my favourite postgres adds ~24 bytes to each row, even if I store 3 integers there - which is too much and will consume a lot of ram

Comment: @Alp well, there might be some inequality between their math expectation, but it won't be huge - so it's better to assume it's a pure random thing

Comment: So creating and filling the structure shouldn't take more than 10 hours? Or a lookup of a word shouldn't?

Comment: @sweeneyrod both operations. Creating and performing ~20 millions of lookups.

Comment: @Spaceman Thanks for clarifying that. My gut feeling is that that time limit shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 4):

I would map each unique string to a numeric ID then associate a [bloom filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter#Space_and_time_advantages) with around 20 bits per element for your <0.1% error rate. 20 bits * 10000 elements * 3 million keys is 75GB so if you are space limited, then store a smaller less accurate filter in memory and the more accurate filter on disk which is called up if the first filter says it might be a match.

There are [alternatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter#Alternatives), but they will only reduce the size from 1.44·n·ln<sub>2</sub>(1/*ε*) to n·ln<sub>2</sub>(1/*ε*) per key, in your case *ε=0.001* so the theoretical limit is a data structure of 99658 bits per key, or 10 bits per element, which would be 298,974,000,000 bits or 38 GB.

So 30GB is below the theoretical limit for a data structure with the performance and number of entries that you require, but within the ball park.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to maintain your own in-memory *data-structure*? Why not use a regular database for this purpose? If that is too slow, why no use an *in-memory database*? One solution is to use in-memory `sqlite3`. Check this SO link, for example: [Fast relational Database for simple use with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18087430/fast-relational-database-for-simple-use-with-python)

You create the in-memory database by passing `':memory:'` to `connect` method.

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
```

What will your schema be? I can think of a wide-schema, with a string as an `id` key (e.g. 'computer', 'house' in your example and about 10000 additional columns: 'field1' to 'field10000'; one of each element of your array). Once you construct the schema, iteratively inserting your data in the database will be simple: *one SQL statement* per row of your data. And from your description, the `insert` part is *one-time-only*. There are no further modifications to the database.

The biggest question is retrieval (more crucially, speed of retrieval). Retrieving entire array for a single key like `computer` is again a simple SQL statement. The scalability and speed is something I don't have an idea about and this is something you will have to experiment. There is still hope that in-memory database will speed up the retrieval part. Yet, I believe that this is the *cheapest* and *fastest* solution you can implement and test (much cheaper than multiple node cluster)

Why am I suggesting this solution? Because the setup that you have in mind is extremely similar to that of a fast-growing database-backed internet startup. All good startups have similar number of requests per day; use some sort of database with caching (Caching would be next thing to look for your problem if a simple database doesn't scale to million requests. Again, it is much *easier* and *cheaper* than buying RAM/nodes).

Comment: This would waste memory if some words had less than 10,000 synonyms, which seems likely.

Comment: From his description, it seems that data is structured with exactly 10k records. In case of less, details will matter. We can still remain memory efficient if large number of records are big

Comment: well, thanks for the idea. Though I think redis would be faster, isn't it? it must be faster, and it must have a smaller overhead, just because it lacks RDBMS features such as filtering, ordering, joins etc. etc. But even with Redis it won't be very fast and compact - need to find a way to reduce array size so bloom filters might help